# Best practice to keep source code of phonegap project for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using mac os x. I'm working on phonegap app for both android and ios. Now the same source code (www folder) in two locations for android and ios. It is inconvenience to update source codes at both location. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Cordova CLI](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli) provides a good example on how to organise your sources when developing for Cordova/PhoneGap.